# An array only allowing certain values 0-9 & A-F for Java

Tags: java, arrays, rgb

Full working now and code is complete Thanks for the help.

Comment: write a class which wraps (encapsulates) the array and have a method that checks the input before inserting it into the array.

Comment: what you have tried ? give some code..

Comment: Are you storing the values in string or in numbers? Really, give some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict user to enter another value by this: (This program is for if You are taking values from user). This will asks for number until you enter number within 0 to 9.

You can make your code according to this. (This is just for your reference, How can you restrict user to enter wrong thing)

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
int i=-1;
i=scan.nextInt();
while(i<=0 && i>=9){
    i=scan.nextInt();
}
```

EDIT

As per your comment, In that case you need to change this as:

```
String s="";
while(!s.matches("^[0-9A-F]+$")){
    s=scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I see where you are going codeMaker, I believe I will use this but change it from an int to String as I also need them to be able to enter A-F and not just 0-9 for the RGB values.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class to hold the RGB values and have it check that the correct values are entered.  See the test code below.... you can expand as you need to handle more cases.

```
import java.util.*;

public class jtest
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new jtest();
  }

  public jtest()
  {
    ArrayList<RGB> RGBarray = new ArrayList<RGB>();

    try
    {
    RGBarray.add(new RGB("F"));
    RGBarray.add(new RGB("J"));
    }
    catch(BadRGBValueException BRGBVE)
    {
      BRGBVE.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  class BadRGBValueException extends Exception
  {
    public BadRGBValueException(String message)
    {
      super(message);
    }
  }

  class RGB
  {
    public RGB(String input) throws BadRGBValueException
    {
      if (!input.matches("^[0-9A-F]+$"))
      {
        throw new BadRGBValueException(input + " is not a valid RGB value");
      }

      value = input;
    }

    private String value = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated Jco.Owens, love it and that code will help me progress on this, Thank you.

Comment: If it helps, please accept this as the answer or give it some points as useful.